# Fill up another column based on another columns unique value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this csv data(an example):

[image: csv data]

I have 5000 zip codes with other columns but 34(zipcode) of them are only unique. I have to take each zipcode and hit another API to get the median income but how can I fill up the other row's median income column with a duplicate zip code?

N.B: Didn't find anything related to my case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get what do you want to do, could you please rephrase it somehow? Do you want to duplicate the ZIP column? Do you want to get the unique values?

Comment: What's the output of this other API? A dictionary?

Comment: @OliverHnat suppose I get 34 median income for 34 unique zip codes but I want to fill up the median income for duplicate zipcode with values I got.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva It's not a problem actually.

Answer (score 1):

You want to us [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), which returns a DataFrame with the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values.

You will need to write a function that takes a zip code and returns the median value. See this example:

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_med(zip_code):
    # This would be your get call to the API
    # Here, `zip_code` is a Series, use `.iloc[0]` 
    # to get the value of the group 
    return zip_code.iloc[0] * 100

df = pd.DataFrame({"zip":[1, 2, 3, 1, 1]})
df["med_income"] = df.groupby("zip")["zip"].transform(get_med)
#    zip  med_income
# 0    1         100
# 1    2         200
# 2    3         300
# 3    1         100
# 4    1         100
```

---

Alternatively you could generate all the median values in a `dict` and then `map` that back onto the DataFrame:

```py
medians = {get_median(zip_code) for zip_code in df["zip"].unique()}
df["med_income"] = df["zip"].map(medians)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for pandas [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). So let's suppose the output of this second API is a dictionary (maybe you can manage to get it):

```py
# Get unique zip codes to use as input to the API
zip_codes = df['Zip'].unique()

# Let's suppose you get an ouput like this
zip_dict = {46234: 1500, 46250: 2000, 46280: 1200} # and so on...
```

So, you can map the zip code to the Median Income like this:

```py
df['Median Income'] = df['Zip'].map(zip_dict)
```

where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: Also, another option would be merge the output (as a dataframe containg both "Zip" and "Median Income" columns) with `df`. Using `map` is simpler, though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to get the unique values of the zipcodes? If yes, then you can use

```
df.yourColumn.unique()
```